# python.exe-entry Point Not Found when opening jupyter notebook

Tags: python

I just created a new environment in anaconda and installed some libraries, when I opened jupyter notebook,  I got below error.  After clicking on OK, I can still open jupyter notebook. But it cannot run.

Anyone can help? Thank you so much!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Deleted the `pythoncomXX.dll` in the exact folder path that is shown in the error message (`C:\<....>\miniconda3\envs\liveproject\Library\bin\pythoncom38.dll`.)